# Simple Printing in c# XAML App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

So i need to print a label from a windows 8 app,(c# Xaml), and all of the samples i've found are overcomplicated for my needs.
My content is a seperate page, containing a Text block and an image, which are filled when the page loads, all i need it to do is print that page. Is there a simplified method for printing ( ie, no using RichTextBox and Overflows etc) for a single simple page. For the interested, this is the page i need to print:

```
<Page
x:Class="Storeageapp.OutputforLabel"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Storeageapp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Width="300" Height="200">
<Grid x:Name="printableArea">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <StackPanel x:Name="header" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="60"  Visibility="Collapsed">

    </StackPanel>

    <TextBlock x:Name="UID" Text="Hello World" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" />

    <Image Source="" x:Name="scenarioImage"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10"/>

    <StackPanel x:Name="footer"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed">

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

I'd be happy if there was some way to print it as an image even but i can't figure that out.
Thanks.
edit: This is in a windows store app sorry, not WPF.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform basic printing in WPF using the [`PrintDialog` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog(v=vs.110).aspx). From the example in the linked page:

```
private void InvokePrint(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create the print dialog object and set options
    PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
    pDialog.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
    pDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;

    // Display the dialog. This returns true if the user presses the Print button.
    Nullable<Boolean> print = pDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (print == true)
    {
        XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument("C:\\FixedDocumentSequence.xps", FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocSeq = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
        pDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDocSeq.DocumentPaginator, "Test print job");
    }
}
```

However, it is possible to print with even less code than that:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
document.ColumnWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true) printDialog.PrintDocument(
    ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)document).DocumentPaginator, "Flow Document Print Job");
```

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, i'm using a Windows Store app, not WPF.

Comment: @Sheridan. Good example - thank you for sharing. It helped me a lot in my WPF project. +1